# how do I mock or stub a function in Angular when using Cypress?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, cypress

Im using Cypress.io as part of the way that Im testing an Angular 7 app.  I've combed through the docs, forums and blogs, but I dont see a way to mock or stub a function in Angular. Im trying to mock the employee Observable.  I need to have the Employee array contain an employee object so that `this.federalTaxesService.loadFederalTaxes()` function is called. In production, this app gets the Employee array from the NgRx store, but the store is not working correctly when using Cypress for some reason.

```
export class EmployeeTaxDetailsContainerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  watchEmployee$: Subscription;
  watchFederalTaxes$: Subscription;

  federalTaxes$: Observable<any> = this.federalTaxesService.federalTaxes$;
  employees$: Observable<any> = this.employeesService.employees$;

  federalTaxes: FederalTaxes;
  employeeUuid: string;

  constructor(public employeesService: EmployeesFacade, public federalTaxesService: FederalTaxesFacade) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.watchEmployee$ = this.employees$.subscribe((employees: Employee[]) => {
      if (employees && employees.length > 0) {
        this.employeeUuid = employees[0].uuid;
        this.federalTaxesService.loadFederalTaxes(this.employeeUuid);
      }
    });

    this.watchFederalTaxes$ = this.federalTaxes$.subscribe((federalTaxes: FederalTaxes) => {
      if (federalTaxes) {
        this.federalTaxes = federalTaxes;
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.watchFederalTaxes$) {
      this.watchFederalTaxes$.unsubscribe();
    }
    if (this.watchEmployee$) {
      this.watchEmployee$.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didnt end up trying to mock the Observable.  Most of that code is covered in my unit tests.  What I really needed was to have `this.federalTaxes` have a value, which is what the code below does.

```
cy.get('.some-ng-element').then(($el) => {
    const el = $el[0].parentElement;
    const win = el.ownerDocument.defaultView;
    const component = win.ng.probe(el).componentInstance;
    component.federalTaxes = { additionalWithholding: 22299, allowances: 1, filingStatus: 'Single' };
});
```

Comment: Thanks it was very useful for us!  In our case we just needed `const el = $el[0]` rather than the parent element

Comment: Does this way trigger the change detection? I tried to modify a component property, but it didn't trigger the change detection